# geom_bar: color gradient and cross hatches (using gridSVG), transparency issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the awesome `ggplot` package, I want a barplot where the `fill` aesthetic is mapped to a continous variable, actually qvalues and on top of it a texture, actually stripes and cross hatches.

The colour gradient is important because it represents significance while the texture would show the category, "A", "B", and their overlap. So diagonals in one way, the opposite way and cross hatches respectively.
I know a Venn diagram could do the job, but we 35 samples and the comparison will be easier to see I think.

The `fill` is trivial, however, the texture one is tricky. On SO, thanks to [@baptise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471093/baptiste) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110160/how-to-apply-cross-hatching-to-a-polygon-using-the-grid-graphical-system/26110400#26110400) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014492/geom-bar-pictograms-how-to)) I managed to get this output with dummy data:
[image: crossbars]

The issue is the **transparency** of the crosses's background. If it is possible get the `alpha` working on the background in the `grid.patternFill()` function that would be great. Unfortunately, in my hands it doesn't work.

Any help will be much appreciated.

dummy data can loaded here:

```
dfso <- structure(list(Sample = c("S1", "S2", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S2"), 
  qvalue = c(14.704287341, 8.1682824035, 13.5471896224, 6.71158432425, 
  12.3900919038, 5.254886245), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
  2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "overlap", "B"), class = "factor"), 
  value = c(897L, 1082L, 503L, 219L, 388L, 165L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Sample", 
  "qvalue", "type", "value"))
```

Code is here:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("gridSVG")
library("gridExtra")
library("dplyr")
library("RColorBrewer")

cols <- brewer.pal(7,"YlOrRd")
pso <- ggplot(dfso)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = qvalue, linetype = type), width = .8, colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "stack", alpha = 1)+
  theme_classic(18)+
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
     legend.key = element_blank(),
     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  guides(linetype = FALSE) +
  ylab("Count")+
  scale_fill_gradientn("-log10(qvalue)", colours = cols, limits = c(0, 20))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dotted", "solid", "dotted"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 2000))

# gridSVG
pat1 <- pattern(linesGrob(gp = gpar(col="black", lwd = 1)),
                width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"),
                dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1)
pat2 <- pattern(linesGrob(x = unit(0:1, "npc"), y = unit(1:0, "npc"),
                          gp = gpar(col="black", lwd = 1)),
                width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"),
                dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1)
crossGrob <- gTree(children = gList(linesGrob(gp = gpar(col="black", lwd = 1)), linesGrob(x = unit(0:1, "npc"), y = unit(1:0, "npc"), gp = gpar(col="black", lwd = 1))))
registerPatternFill("hash1", pat1)
registerPatternFill("hash2", pat2)
registerPatternFill("cross", grob = crossGrob, dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1, width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"))
gridsvg("crossbars.svg", width = 10)
print(pso)
grid.force()
grid.patternFill("geom_rect.rect", alpha = 0.2, grep = TRUE, group = FALSE,
                 label = rep(c("hash1", "cross", "hash2"), 1))
dev.off()
```

In `grid.patternFill` the `alpha` parameter is suppose to give the transparency, as far as I understood it. But, it has no effect, and the colour is lost. I filled the patterns only for the first bar so you see the contrast.

**Edit**: the `alpha` is working fine, but it acts on the pattern itself, *i.e* the lines. That explains why the lines appear so pale. The issue is more that the background is assumed white and without transparency.

The `linetype` mapping was a attempt to highlight the overlap part, but it is not nice. If the transparency works for `gridSVG` I will discard this part and keep a solid line all the way.

Many thanks in advance,

Aurelien

If of any use, output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite)
locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] gridExtra_0.9.1    RColorBrewer_1.1-2 dplyr_0.4.1        gridSVG_1.4-3      ggplot2_1.0.1     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6      XML_3.98-1.3     assertthat_0.1   digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-42      plyr_1.8.3       DBI_0.3.1       
 [8] gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.2.5     stringi_0.5-5    reshape2_1.4.1   labeling_0.3     proto_0.3-10    
[15] RJSONIO_1.3-0    tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.2.1   colorspace_1.2-6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but I will provide this following code as reference for someone who might like to see how we might accomplish this task.  A live version is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/6ce03d4324634feba4a9).  I almost think it would be easier to do entirely with `d3` or library built on `d3`

```
library("ggplot2")
library("gridSVG")
library("gridExtra")
library("dplyr")
library("RColorBrewer")

dfso <- structure(list(Sample = c("S1", "S2", "S1", "S2", "S1", "S2"), 
                       qvalue = c(14.704287341, 8.1682824035, 13.5471896224, 6.71158432425, 
                                  12.3900919038, 5.254886245), type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                  2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "overlap", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                       value = c(897L, 1082L, 503L, 219L, 388L, 165L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("Sample", 
                                                                                                                                           "qvalue", "type", "value"))

cols <- brewer.pal(7,"YlOrRd")
pso <- ggplot(dfso)+
  geom_bar(aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = qvalue), width = .8, colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "stack", alpha = 1)+
  ylim(c(0,2000)) + 
  theme_classic(18)+
  theme( panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
         panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
         legend.key = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))+
  ylab("Count")+
  scale_fill_gradientn("-log10(qvalue)", colours = cols, limits = c(0, 20))

# use svglite and htmltools
library(svglite)
library(htmltools)

# get the svg as tag
pso_svg <- htmlSVG(print(pso),height=10,width = 14)

browsable(
  attachDependencies(
    tagList(
      pso_svg,
      tags$script(
        sprintf(
"
  var data = %s

  var svg = d3.select('svg');

  svg.select('style').remove();

  var bars = svg.selectAll('rect:not(:last-of-type):not(:first-of-type)')
     .data(d3.merge(d3.values(d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.Sample}).map(data))))

  bars.style('fill',function(d){
    var t = textures
              .lines()
              .background(d3.rgb(d3.select(this).style('fill')).toString());

    if(d.type === 'A') t.orientation('2/8');
    if(d.type === 'overlap') t.orientation('2/8','6/8');
    if(d.type === 'B') t.orientation('6/8');

    svg.call(t);
    return t.url();
  });
"    
          ,
          jsonlite::toJSON(dfso)
        )
      )
    ),
    list(
      htmlDependency(
        name = "d3",
        version = "3.5",
        src = c(href = "http://d3js.org"),
        script = "d3.v3.min.js"
      ),
      htmlDependency(
        name = "textures",
        version = "1.0.3",
        src = c(href = "https://rawgit.com/riccardoscalco/textures/master/"),
        script = "textures.min.js"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks @timelyportfolio! It does work, I am accepting the answer as this is the best we have now. `svglite` + `textures` are overlaying nicely. Could be improved for sure but already great.

Comment: i'm wondering how well it scales.  also, it assumes the data stays in its original order.

Comment: it won't be for a large number of bars anyway, won't be readable. And my previous attempt was also expecting the same ordering. The best would be a `ggplot` extension that map texture to a variable, but that's beyond my skills.

Answer (score 5):

I am answering my own question, as there is a way to fill a specific color to the pattern thank to this [link](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Reports/leaf/leaf.html#fig-barchart-pattern).
On the first bar, for category "A", it could look like this:
[image: cross]

replacing the `pat1` pattern by the following code:

```
pat1 <- pattern(gTree(children=gList(
                      rectGrob(gp=gpar(col=NA, fill=cols[4])),
                      linesGrob(gp=gpar(col="black", lwd = 5)))),
                      width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"),
                      dev.width = 1, dev.height = 1)
```

For `geom_bar` with few colours, it would work but for my issue where the `fill` colour is mapped to a heatmap scale, it is going to be tedious.

Comment: I don't know the answer but perhaps if we look on the SVG side we can get some help.  Have you seen https://riccardoscalco.github.io/textures/?  I'll try to play with it a little today to see what I can discover.

Comment: @timelyportfolio thanks! Didn't know about it. I don't absolutely want to stick to gridSVG, anyway this project seems not so active. Might be better to switch to another approach for applying the textures.

Comment: how are you planning to use this?  what is the final output?

Comment: Actually we publish it here http://m.nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2015/09/03/nar.gkv863/F5.expansion.html using the the filling on one hand and the pattern on the other overlayed in illustrator. A shame but at least you can see how we wanted to do it. Thanks again for your kind help