# How to use an R script from GitHub?

Tags: r, github

I am trying to use an R script hosted on GitHub [plugin-draw.R](https://github.com/byzheng/leaflet/blob/5c207af4764dc83e1736e1e4dd8e88e9fca84856/R/plugin-draw.R). How should I use this plugin?

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use  [source_url](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6/topics/source_url) from package `devtools`, using the url you get by clicking on `raw` on the files 's Github page:

```
library(devtools)
source_url("https://raw.github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/master/R/bingSearchXScraper/bingSearchXScraper.R")
```

##### Edit: use simply `source()`

Since recent versions of R, it seems you can simply use `source()` with the same "raw" url:

```r
source("https://raw.github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/master/R/bingSearchXScraper/bingSearchXScraper.R")
ls()
#> [1] "bingSearchXScraper"
```

Comment: this basically works but it seems that the e.g. the roxygen comments are not fetched. E.g. when running `source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/3dgeo-heidelberg/pytreedb/224339bc03918aadeed4ca1345ce9feeb312536f/examples_api/example.R")`

Answer (score 7):

You can use solution offered on [**R-Bloggers**](http://www.r-bloggers.com/source_https-sourcing-an-r-script-from-github-over-https/):

```
source_github <- function(u) {
  # load package
  require(RCurl)
 
  # read script lines from website
  script <- getURL(u, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
 
  # parase lines and evaluate in the global environment
  eval(parse(text = script))
}
 
source_github("https://raw.github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/master/R/bingSearchXScraper/bingSearchXScraper.R")
```

For the function to be evaluated in a global environment *(I'm guessing that you will prefer this solution)* you can use:

```
source_https <- function(u, unlink.tmp.certs = FALSE) {
  # load package
  require(RCurl)
 
  # read script lines from website using a security certificate
  if(!file.exists("cacert.pem")) download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile = "cacert.pem")
  script <- getURL(u, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = "cacert.pem")
  if(unlink.tmp.certs) unlink("cacert.pem")
 
  # parase lines and evealuate in the global environement
  eval(parse(text = script), envir= .GlobalEnv)
}
 
source_https("https://raw.github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/master/R/bingSearchXScraper/bingSearchXScraper.R")
source_https("https://raw.github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/master/R/htmlToText/htmlToText.R", unlink.tmp.certs = TRUE)
```

---

*As mentioned in the [the original article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/source_https-sourcing-an-r-script-from-github-over-https/) by [**Tony Breyal**](http://www.r-bloggers.com/author/tony-breyal/), [this discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229859/sourcing-an-r-script-from-github-for-global-session-use-from-within-a-wrapper) should also be credited as it is relevant to the discussed question.*

Answer (score 7):

Based on [@Matifou's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175483/4668450), but using the "new" method appending `?raw=TRUE` at the end of your URL:

```
devtools::source_url("https://github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/blob/master/R/bingSearchXScraper/bingSearchXScraper.R?raw=TRUE")
```

Comment: This works in that when you paste it into a browser, it will redirect you to a url with the token included, but it still gives me a 404 when I try to use it with `devtools::source_url`.

Answer (score 6):

If it is a link on GitHub where you can click on `Raw` next to the `Blame`, you can actually just use the ordinary `base::source`. Go to the R script of your choice and find the `Raw` button.

[image]

The link will contain `raw.githubusercontent.com` now, and the page show nothing but R script itself. Then, for this example,

```
source(
  paste0(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/betanalpha/knitr_case_studies/master/", 
    "stan_intro/stan_utility.R"
  )
)
```

(`paste0` was used just to fit the URL into a narrower screen.)